# erb gives me - undefined local variable or method for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, erb

erb gives me `undefined local variable or method  for main:Object (NameError)` unless the variable used in erb template is a global variable.

**Is that correct?** on ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

Below is code that works. If I remove `$` from the variable name  ($db, $db_root, $db_root_password) I get the error.

```
$db = get_single_argument("database name")
$db_root = get_single_argument("database root user name")
$db_root_passwd = get_single_argument("database root user password")

mysql_commands = get_conf_file("installer_mysql.erb")

puts mysql_commands.result  #gives me the error
```

and **get_conf_file** procedure

```
def get_conf_file(file)

 return_array = Array.new
 if (File.exists?(file))
   return_array = ERB.new File.read(file)
 end
 return_array
end
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace and the line of code where you actually execute the ERB template?  Nothing should happen until `#result` is called on the template, which requires the binding of the caller to be passed in (which contains all the variable references).

Comment: Ignore that, I saw what your code was doing. See my answer for an explanation ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby has a concept called a [binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html), which you might think of as the local variables, value of self, block etc. that a piece of code might have. You might also think of a binding as the code's context.

Erb's `result` method takes an optional second method which is the binding with which to evaluate the code you give it, so you can do stuff like

```
x = 1
ERB.new('x=<%= x %>').result(binding) #=> "x=1"
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Works nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in the binding of the caller, and you should be:

```
puts mysql_commands.result(binding)
```

The binding contains all the variable references in the current scope.